Error sending message: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
My website use smtp.gmail.com to send emails. The service has stopped. Error sending message: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
The script has working witthout problem for months.
require '/var/www/html/vendor/autoload.php';
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->isSMTP();                                            // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';                 // Specify main mail server
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                                     // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'admin@fanmail.biz';                     // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'b1oema57_removed'; 
$mail->setFrom('admin@fanmail.biz', 'Fanmail.biz');
$mail->addReplyTo('admin@fanmail.biz', 'Reply To Name');
$mail->addAddress($email2);
$mail->Subject = "Fanmail Alerts - Password & Activation Link";
$mail->Body = "Hello,...";
if(!$mail->send()) {
$message3 = "Error sending message: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
else {
$message3 = "<font color=\"#FF0000\">Inactivated Account.<br>Password and an activation link have been     sent to $email2.</font>";
}</sub>

I have contacted my hosting company about the problem. Here is their reply:
I have confirmed that the connection to "smtp.gmail.com" on port 587 via telnet was successful. This indicates that the server is functioning properly, and there are no connection issues between your server and Gmail's server. I recommend reaching out to Gmail support for assistance with any SMTP-related problems you may be encountering, as they are best positioned to address specific issues with their service.
[root@ded93 ~]# telnet smtp.gmail.com 587
Trying 142.251.116.109...
Connected to smtp.gmail.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP 46e09a7af769-7155686c95bsm478175a34.73 - gsmtp


SMTP port 587  = Enable Start TLS encryption.  ADD $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS;

Step into the debugger:
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2; // Set to 2 to see detailed debugging output
$mail->Debugoutput = 'html'; // Change this to 'error_log' to send output to the server's error log

Hopefully the output gives further clarifications.
Another guess would be that your website has reached some monthly quota of google services.
Also check your server logs for any weird occurrences.
Enabling TLS encryption, like @life888888 pointed out, is something that depends on the implementation. If you insist on using SMTP, you have to enable TLS. This post goes into further details. Here is @life888888's advice. I repeat it here for better visibility:
$mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS;

If nothing helps, contact the google support.
